# Why is my PHP page submitting a form through the page that redirected it?

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have an index.php that checks if the user is logged in, if not it redirects the user to the login page as follows:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["page_identifier"] = "index"; 
    include "inc/header.php"; 

    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) OR !$_SESSION["loggedin"] == TRUE){
        echo "ERROR: Not logged in!";
        header("Refresh: 3; url = login.php");
    }
    else{
         ......
    }
?>
```

This is the login page.

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION["page_identifier"] = "login";
    $_SESSION["form_identifier"] = "login";   
    include "inc/header.php"; 
?>
    <div>
        <form action="submission.php" name="login" method="POST">
            <input class="textBox" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" maxlength="20"/>
            <input class="textBox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" maxlength="20"/><br><br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        <form class="register" action="register.php">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="New user? Register"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php include "inc/footer.php"; ?>
```

Each page sets the `$_SESSION["form_identifier"]` to its page name, when a form is submitted I check in the submission file from where it came from as follows:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["page_identifier"] = "submission";
    
    //checking if the form is a login form.
    if($_SESSION["form_identifier"] == "login"){
        .......
    }
```

It show that the from comes from "NULL" not from "login". Why does this happen, and is there a way to change this?

Comment: It appears you forgot to put `session_start();` at the top of the login page

Comment: P.s. just a tip, putting the page identifiers in the session will cause unexpected behaviour and possibly bugs if users open your site in more than one tab of their browser, and then keep switching between them - which is quite common behaviour. Those tabs will share the same session so it's easy to see there could be confusion on the server about which page the request came "from" in reality. Browser usage isn't necessarily a linear process.

Comment: @ADyson, Wow! I was cracking my head open to figure this out... I forgot to check the basics lol...

Comment: @ADyson, about the tip you wrote. Is there a better way of doing this? I am a newbie to server-side programming.

Comment: Well, the exact details depends a little bit. Does your site have any public pages or is it all private except for the login page? And what are the scenarios where you actually need to know the page/URL you came _from_ (as opposed to the page/URL which is being processed _now_)? In my experience of this sort of thing, it's necessary to know the URL of the login page so that when loading the login page, the code doesn't go "user isn't logged in, redirect the to the login page", and thus create an infinite loop...

Comment: ...the only other time you need to know which page you're on _now_ is if some pages are private and some are public, so that again, you can decide whether the user needs to be redirected if they're not logged in or not. That can be achieved by having a list (in a file or database) of the pages which require the user to be logged in, and their URLs. That or you put code into each of those pages which checks, but then you usually end up with redundant code - better to centralise it.

Comment: @ADyson, I have a sumbission page and I want it to handle a few forms, so it has to know what form it's getting. I ended up adding a hidden field to all the forms which has the form type for example "login" as the value, that's how it know how to handle it.

Comment: Yes that's the right approach to that really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by ADyson in the comments, i forgot to put "session_start();" in the login page.